# Android GraphView - how to fill area under the Line Graph with color?

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

I have created a LineGraph, it´s look like this:

[image]

But I want fill the area below the grap like this:

[image]

How can I implement this feature? Can you help me?

Comment: too damn late, but was you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `setDrawBackground` method to enable it.

```
LineGraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(this,"My Line Graph");
graphView.setDrawBackground(true);
```

Comment: It´s also need to set setBackgroundColor()

Comment: is there any way to draw the background only for specific series?

Comment: I can't find this property in current version

Comment: what is the name of this library ?

Answer (score 2):

For more current versions of GraphView, set the background colour and drawBackground on the series:

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_GRAPH_ID_HERE);
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> mySeries = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
    new DataPoint(0, 0),
    new DataPoint(1, 5),
    new DataPoint(2, 10)
});

mySeries.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
mySeries.setDrawBackground(true);

graph.addSeries(mySeries);
```